# What's the proper way to set up a class to initialize public variables in c#?

Tags: c#, web-services

I have created the class at the bottom in c#. This class is referenced by webservices to determine user accesses, like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public List<FAFSA> getFAFSA(string pageID)
{
    formValues fv = new formValues();
    string personID = fv.personID;
    List<FAFSA> lf = new List<FAFSA>();

    if (fv.secBlur == "no_secBlur")
    {
        FAFSA f = new FAFSA();
        f.fafsaCheck = "0";
        lf.Add(f);
    }

    ...
}
```

I'm trying to add the two variables fafsa and staff. The method getSecBlur() is returning all three values from my database for secBlur, fafsa, and staff. So how do I set up this class, so that the SecBlur method is only called once but populates all three of my variables so that they can be used in webservice calls?  It will not work the way it is now because it says fafsa and staff need to be static, but if I make them static, then in the webservices it says that the members must be accessed with an instance reference.

Sorry if this isn't worded to well, but I'm new to this and still trying to learn...

```
public class formValues : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public string userName = getUserName();
    public string firstName = getFirstName();
    public string personID = getPersonID();
    public int fafsa = 0;
    public int staff = 0;
    public string secBlur = getSecBlur();

    private static string getUserDataString(int ix)
    {
        string retValue = "";

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

            if (authCookie != null)
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

                if (ticket != null)
                {
                    string[] userData = { "" };

                    char[] delimiterChar = { '|' };
                    userData = ticket.UserData.Split(delimiterChar);
                    if (userData.Length > 1)
                        retValue = userData[ix];
                    else
                    {
                        FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); 

                        string redirUrl = "/DMC/loginNotFound.html";
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(redirUrl, false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return retValue;
    }

    private static string getUserName()
    {
        //This retrieves the person logged into windows/active directory
        WindowsPrincipal wp = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
        //string[] fullUsername = wp.Identity.Name.Split('\\');
        string fullUsername = wp.Identity.Name;

        return fullUsername;
    }

    private static string getFirstName()
    {
        string firstName = getUserDataString(1);

        return firstName;
    }

    private static string getPersonID()
    {
        string personID = getUserDataString(0);

        return personID;
    }

    private static string getSecBlur()
    {
        string secBlur = "no_secBlur";

        string mySQL = "exec get_UserAdminStatus @personID";
        string cf = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DistrictAssessmentDWConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cf);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(mySQL, connection);

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@personID", getUserDataString(0));

        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
        connection.Close();

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (dt.Rows[0]["secBlur"].ToString() == "1")
                secBlur = "secBlur";

            fafsa = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["fafsa"]);
            staff = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["staff"]);
        }

        return secBlur;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you give any class static, public values the so called "Static" (or type) Constructor will be called to do the initialization work before any access is done: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors

Another common way to do initlizsation or define default values, is to use the Factory Pattern. Afaik the Graphics Class in XNA has to adapt depending if you run ona X-Box or PC, so it uses the Factory Pattern.

Of coruse with Web(anything) there is the whole issue with variable Scope, even for Statics. Much less local variables.